# Needed to filter null values from JSON response in spring boot project

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, okhttp

public class APIService {

```
private List<CoinDTO> coinList = new ArrayList<>();

private final TrackerConfigProperties trackerConfig;

//Injecting configuration properties into the constructor.
public APIService(TrackerConfigProperties trackerConfig) {
    this.trackerConfig = trackerConfig;
}

public List<CoinDTO> getCoinList() {
    return coinList;
}

public void setCoinList(List<CoinDTO> coinList) {
    this.coinList = coinList;
}

@PostConstruct
@Scheduled(cron = "* * 1 * * *")
public void getAPIData() throws IOException, JSONException{     
    List<CoinDTO> newData = new ArrayList<>();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    
    JSONObject obj = null;
    JSONObject data = null;

    //Use request builder to configure api 
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(trackerConfig.apiUrl())
        .get()
        .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", trackerConfig.apiKey())
        .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", trackerConfig.apiHost())
        .build();
    
    Response response = null;
    
    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    
        String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
        System.out.println(jsonResponse);

        
        obj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        data = obj.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray arr = data.getJSONArray("coins");
                    
        System.out.println(arr);

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++) {
            CoinDTO coinRecords = new CoinDTO();
            coinRecords.setName(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
            coinRecords.setSymbol(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("symbol"));
            coinRecords.setPrice(arr.getJSONObject(i).getFloat("price"));
            coinRecords.setRank(arr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("rank"));
            coinRecords.setChange(arr.getJSONObject(i).getFloat("change"));
            coinRecords.setUrl(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("iconUrl"));
            coinRecords.setMarketCap(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("marketCap"));
            newData.add(coinRecords);
        }
        this.coinList = newData;
        
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    // Requesting response.body().string() more than once will cause illegal state exception.   
}
```

}

The JSON response from crypto API looks very fishy. 1-60 results, there is no problem in getting the data. But when I increase the response count to 100 coins. A few of them have null values and this is giving me number format exception. As shown below,

```
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["change"] is not a number.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getFloat(JSONObject.java:655) ~[json-20180130.jar:na]
    at com.vish.trackerapp.service.APIService.getAPIData(APIService.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:424) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:368) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:192) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:476) ~[na:na]
    at org.json.JSONObject.getFloat(JSONObject.java:653) ~[json-20180130.jar:na]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Json response is as follows,

```
{
                "uuid": "aQx_vW8s1",
                "symbol": "XEC",
                "name": "eCash",
                "color": null,
                "iconUrl": "https://cdn.coinranking.com/wdqRaUEhn/xec.png",
                "marketCap": "458134192",
                "price": "0.000023888579923343",
                "listedAt": 1634887994,
                "tier": 1,
                "change": "0.07",
                "rank": 73,
                "sparkline": [
                    "0.000023888455899517",
                    "0.000023873825475088",
                    "0.00002383507280166",
                    "0.000023738913764452",
                    "0.000023705304867018",
                    "0.000023643911925818",
                    "0.000023626155269768",
                    "0.000023699523887097",
                    "0.000023745220955252",
                    "0.000023820571142281",
                    "0.000023801617704237",
                    "0.000023816460854558",
                    "0.000023795169626986",
                    "0.000023858079419847",
                    "0.000023892553157129",
                    "0.000023849240281632",
                    "0.000023857584839752",
                    "0.000024048737766589",
                    "0.00002392004515143",
                    "0.000023808725016789",
                    "0.000023751508927767",
                    "0.000023764344487179",
                    "0.000023826878245569",
                    "0.000023885406955056",
                    "0.000023888537567965"
                ],
                "lowVolume": false,
                "coinrankingUrl": "https://coinranking.com/coin/aQx_vW8s1+ecash-xec",
                "24hVolume": "5918517",
                "btcPrice": "1.416302521e-9"
            }
```

I tried this idea, but couldn't figure it out how to include in my code.

```
            newData.stream().filter(v -> v != null);
```

Greatly appreciate any suggestions or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a good solution would be to use a mapper and a DTO to deal with the json, since there you could use the @JsonProperty tag that allows you to make the json field not mandatory.

**Here's how to use a mapper:**

```
 ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        JSONObject battle= new JSONObject(text);
        JSONObject battleObject = battle.getJSONObject(JsonObject);
        try{
            Battle battleDto =  om.readValue(battleObject.toString(), Battle.class);
            return battleDto;
        }catch (JsonProcessingException e ){
            throw new NoStarPlayerException("No starPlayer for this battle ="+battle.toString());
        }
```

**And here the DTO:**

```
public class Battle {
    @JsonProperty("battleTime")
    String battletime;
    @JsonIgnore()
    String map;
    @JsonProperty("mode")
    String mode;
    @JsonProperty("type")
    String type;
    @JsonProperty("result")
    String result;
    @JsonProperty("duration")
    int duration;
    @JsonProperty("trophyChange")
    int trophyChange;
    @JsonProperty("starPlayer")
    StarPlayer starPlayer;
    @JsonProperty("teams")
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Player>> teams;
    @JsonProperty("players")
    ArrayList<Player>players;
    @JsonProperty("rank")
    int rank;
```

To work around a missing Json field, you can use @JsonIgnore(If you are not interested in the field ever) or @JsonProperty(value = "battleTime",required = false) if it may or may not be null.

I hope I have helped you, Regards

Comment: Appreciate for your response and very detailed explanation. Your explanation was very clear. But, I figured it out that to try using spring boot's default exclusions.  I included these lines in application.properties and it worked without any extra code. spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=ALWAYS
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_ABSENT
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_DEFAULT
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_EMPTY

Answer (score 0):

json.org library that you use is a good training tool for JSON but not very good for practical use. The best libraries available are [JSON-Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) (of Google). I personally prefer JSON-Jackson. Use one of those to parse your JSON and you will solve your problem easily. 
Also, For simplistic case like this I wrote my own thin wrapper over JSON-Jackson library that allows you to serialize and parse and serialize JSON to/from java class. Here is [Javadoc for JsonUtils class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html).
Your code may look something like this:

```
   HashMap<String, Object> map;
    try {
        map = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonStr, Map.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
```

Instead of Map you can write your own DTO class and than substitute `Map.class` with your own class instance. JsonUtils class comes with Open Source MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. The library can be obtained from Maven Central [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)